# Quotes and parameter substitution over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, quotes

I have a command that I'm trying to run over SSH but I don't know how to wrap it correctly in quotes. Here are 2 attempts below, none of them is doing what I want.

A) The command is wrapped in double quotes

```
version=1.1
ssh nrichard@myserver.com "
    cd /home/nrichard/${version}
    ls | while read filename ; do 
        echo $filename
        hive -f $filename &
    done"
```

> This will be able to go to the correct directory /home/nrichard/1.1
>   But the while loop won't work because $filename is replaced by an empty string before the command is sent over ssh.
>   On the other hand...

B) The command is wrapped in single quotes

```
version=1.1
ssh nrichard@myserver.com '
    cd /home/nrichard/${version}
    ls | while read filename ; do 
        echo $filename
        hive -f $filename &
    done'
```

> This will not be able to go to the correct directory /home/nrichard/1.1. It will try to go to '/home/nrichard/${version}' which is not a directory that exists, nor the one I want to go to.
>   But the while loop will work fine.

Any ideas on how to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about escaping the variables that you don't want your shell to expand, while using double quotes to wrap the whole thing?

```
version=1.1
ssh nrichard@myserver.com "
    cd /home/nrichard/${version}
    ls | while read filename ; do 
        echo \$filename
        hive -f \$filename &
    done"
```

Comment: Thanks @codeforester. That works.
I'll accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of any quoting issue at the cost of an additional file on disk, try this.

In a separate (local) file, type in the commands you want to execute on the remote host.  They would use normal quoting (like you would use on the command line normally).

```
cat name_of_file_containing_commands | ssh user@host bash
```

Piping lines of text to bash causes execution of this text (it works locally too, try it).  In this case you simply use ssh as a "networked pipe".

You can also avoid the useless `cat`, of course :

```
ssh user@host bash <name_of_file_containing_commands
```